# How can I clear the "Redownload" history on my Nintendo Switch eShop?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop

In the eShop on my Nintendo Switch, when I click on my profile picture to see my Account Information, there is a button called **Redownload**.

In the past I downloaded some free games which are really bad and that I will never download again, and because I deleted them from the Switch they are shown in this Redownload list.

How can I clear this list? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find an official answer, but I cannot find something for it (just like you) and people over the internet as well. Therefor I think **it is not possible** unfortunately.

Comments on form example [GameFaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/189706-nintendo-switch/answers/502866-how-can-i-delete-redownload-list-on-e-shop) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/bux9cp/another_idea_for_switcheshop_ability_to_hide/).